# Getting a list of authors with the numbers or counts of their respective posts in django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get author's list from my post `model` which has a field (author_name) related to the author `model` with a (`ForeignKey).`Using `Post.objects.all()` gets the list alright, but if I have a John Doe (Author) with 3 posts, I get John Doe listed three times with the respective post title. What I want is to list John once with numbers (count) of his posts so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) on a query on Author.

```
from django.db.models import Count
authors_with_counts = Author.objects.all().annotate(Count('post'))
```

Now each author has a `post__count` attribute containing the number of posts for which they are the author.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you, to let future readers know it solved the problem.